# How do I mock angular's $http with sinon?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I am trying to do a simple mock of angular's $http with sinon in a Mocha test.

But my spy never has any results in it no matter what I try.

searchResource.typeAhead is my function under test.  It calls $http based on its arguments and I want to make sure the request is correct.

searchResource.typeAhead returns a promise, but I tried putting the checking code in .then() and it never executes.

```
suite('Search Resource', function() {

  var injector = angular.injector(['cannonball-client-search', 'cannonball-client-core']);
  var searchResource = injector.get('SearchResource');

  suite('#typeAhead()', function () {
    setup(function () {
      this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
      this.server.respondWith('GET',
        config.endpoints.search.typeAhead,
        [200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]']);
      this.spyhttp = sinon.spy(injector.get('$http'));
    });
    teardown(function () {
      this.server.restore();
    });
    test('positive', function (done) {
      searchResource.typeAhead(
        'expl',
        [{entityType: 'itementity'}],
        [{createdBy: 'Eric'}, {createdBy: 'Tal'}],
        10
      );
      this.server.respond();
      expect(this.spyhttp.calledWith({
        method: 'get',
        url: config.endpoints.search.typeAhead +
        '?query=expl&filter=entityType:itementity&orfilter=createdBy:Eric&orfilter=createdBy:Tal&limit=10'
      })).to.be.true();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try using `$httpBackend` ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: The short answer is that you don't use sinon to mock `$http`. See @Phil's resource for what you need to use instead. It's based on the ng framework calls and so you will find it much, much easier to test with.

Comment: Ok so I "don't" - can you explain why I shouldn't be able to?  Sinon is supposed to be able to mock anything right?  Why not $http?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies outside of Sinon mocking.

If `angular.injector` is used directly instead of suggested [`angular.mock.module` and `angular.mock.inject` helpers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module), the one is on his own with it and his knowledge of Angular injector.

The obvious downside is that the injector won't be torn down automatically after each spec (while it would be when `angular.mock.module` is used), so all nested specs operate on the same instance of Angular injector.

At this point

```
  var searchResource = injector.get('SearchResource');
```

`SearchResource` service instance was already injected with unmocked `$http`, that's the end of the story. Even if it wouldn't, there's no chance that Angular will ever know that `this.spyhttp` spy should be used instead of original `$http` service. Its methods can be spied after the instantiation

```
sinon.spy($http, 'get');
```

but not `$http` function itself.

The strategy for testing with `angular.injector` may be

```
var $httpSpy;
var injector = angular.injector([
  'cannonball-client-search',
  'cannonball-client-core',
  function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$http', function ($delegate) {
      return ($httpSpy = sinon.spy($delegate));
    });
  }
]);

// injector.get('$http') === $httpSpy;
```

Notice that this will make Sinon spy on `$http` function, not on [its methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods).

If the question is about how Angular mocks should be approached with Sinon, then it's as easy as that. Otherwise this may indicate an XY problem, and the other answer addresses it directly (`$httpBackend` and the way `$http` embraces it are there exactly to make the burden of mocking XMLHttpRequest requests non-existent).

Answer (score 3):

Angular was built with testing in mind. The previous comments aren't suggesting that you cannot use sinon to mock out $http, its just not common practice and it definitely won't be as easy to do as it is with $httpBackend.

I would personally only be using sinon to mock any dependencies which don't belong to Angular as such. It's easy enough to provide mock responses with $httpBackend:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/url').respond({
    mock: 'response'
});
```

Now any request to '/url' with use the mock response object. I'm sure $httpBackend has some other complicated wizardry built in to handle other things like interceptors perhaps?